# How to use the ADOBE AIR SDK 3.1 in Flash CS5 on Mac OS X

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I Have downloaded the ADOBE AIR SDK 3.1, I use Flash CS5 on Mac OS X, I Tried to update from 2.0 to 3.1, like I used to update the Flex SDK in Flash (Flash > Preferences > ActionScript > ActionScript 3.0 Settings), couldn't find where I should link to the new SDK folder.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Flash Pro doesn't have an editable setting pointing to the AIR SDK it uses, so you need to duck into its folders and overwrite the SDK it came with. Inside your Flash CS5 install directory there should be a folder called `AIR2.6`. You want to back that up somewhere, and put the new SDK in the same place (with the folder name AIR2.6), and Flash will start using the new SDK.

The other thing you'll want to do is to put an updated `airglobal.swc` in your install folders so that you get AIR3.1 code hinting. See the instructions on [this page](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html) - those describe how to update the IDE to target Flash 11, but the process is similar for AIR except that you update airglobal.swc instead of playerglobal.swc. You can also make some new AIR3 publish profiles, similarly following the instructions on that page for Flash 11.

It's a little tedious but unless somebody makes an .mxp to update for AIR I'm not sure there's an easier way. Good luck!